# What's the difference between git subtree and just git cloning in a subdirectory?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I am starting to get the feeling that a git subtree is just a git clone in a subfolder.

For example:

```
project/
   .git
   foo/
   bar/
   subtree/    # this could be a git subtree or just a git clone folder
   .gitignore
```

would I not get the same effect of a subtree, if I just put subtree in .gitignore, and then just git cloned my other project in the subtree folder? What are the effective differences between git cloning in a subfolder and git subtree?

Answer (score 0):

You can see it that way, but they're not really the same.

For one, subtree creates a relationship on the parent repo to the subtree one. That doesn't happen with a clone in a gitignored directory.
Also subtree helps you track the remote repo without getting all its history (see `--squash`).

Just two differences off the top of my head.